# Certain NPM installs fail with EPERM 50 (Gulp and others)

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I continue to get permissions errors on Windows 7 when trying to npm install certain modules. A global install of gulp for example results in this:

```
c:\Users\abc\Documents\uniform\UniServer\www\ur>npm install -g gulp
/
> v8flags@1.0.1 install C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags
> node fetch.js

flags for v8 3.14.5.9 cached.
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Users\abc\Documents\uniform\UniServer\www\npmcache\c14291c8-che-
ansi-regex-0-2-1-package-tgz.lock'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Users\abc\Documents\uniform\UniServer\www\npmcache\c14291c8-
che-ansi-regex-0-2-1-package-tgz.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\uniform\\UniServer\\www\\npmcache\\c14291c8-che-ans
i-regex-0-2-1-package-tgz.lock' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\n
pm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\abc\Documents\uniform\UniServer\www\ur
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\abc\Documents\uniform\UniServer\www\npmcache\c14291c8-che-ansi-regex-0-2-
1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Users\abc\Documents\uniform\UniServer\www\npmcache\c14291c
8-che-ansi-regex-0-2-1-package-tgz.lock'
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I get this error while running cmd as administrator. I've read in other SO posts that this may represent a missing program. `git` is installed and works so it's not that. `bower` is installed and works. I've tried adding `c:\windows\system32` to the system PATH. No help. As you may be able to tell, I modified the location of my NPM cache thinking that perhaps the folder it was in by default had some sort of permissions issue. No help there either. I've tried adding the --no-bin-links option, doesn't help. I'm really at a loss as to what is causing this problem. Have the same issue trying to install `slush-mongo`, either globally or locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that our company's anti-virus software was actually causing it. We attempted to do exclusions of node.exe and our working directory but both were insufficient. We have to disable the AV software, perform the install, and then re-enable AV.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I too was struggling and was about to give up when I came across this. Turned off my firewall and things work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found these command-line flags that seem to fix it without having to disable AV:

```
npm install --cache-lock-retries 1000 --cache-lock-wait 100000
```

You can change the default values (so you don't need to add the command-line options every time) by running:

```
npm config set cache-lock-retries 1000
npm config set cache-lock-wait 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Which I was able to resolve by opening the command prompt or GIT Bash using RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR OPTION.

STEP 1: Right click on cmd.exe (search cmd in windows) or GIT Bash.

STEP 2: Click on Run as Administrator.

STEP 3: Execute >**npm install** command